# How to Select Radio button inside Fieldset using behat

Tags: behat

Can any one please help me out how to select a radio button if it is inside a fieldset??

I can access individual radio button using foreach but when i try to select it or click it its giving some Ajax error.

HTML code is given below
I have tried to select it with radio button's label as well as given in above comment but not able to select it.

```html
<fieldset id="edit-cvs-options" class="form-wrapper">
    <legend>
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
        <div class="ios-content" style="display: none;">test</div>
        <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-use-stored">
            <label for="edit-use-stored">
                <span>test</span>
                <input id="edit-use-stored" class="form-radio" type="radio" name="use_stored" checked="TRUE" value="on" display-title-fix="1"/>
            </label>
        </div>
        <fieldset id="edit-cvs-1" class="form-wrapper" style="display: inline-block;">
            <div>
                <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-use-uploaded">
                    <label for="edit-use-uploaded">
                        <span>test</span>
                        <input id="edit-use-uploaded" class="form-radio" type="radio" name="use_uploaded" display-title-fix="1" value="off"/>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

This is my Behat step definition:

```php
$session = $this->getSession(); // get the mink session
$escapedValue = $session->getSelectorsHandler()->xpathLiteral('use_uploaded');
$radioButton = $session->getPage()->find('named', array('radio', $escapedValue));
$radioButton ->click();
```

Comment: What step definition are you currently using to try to select it?

Comment: session = $this->getSession(); // get the mink session
                                                                                         $escapedValue = $session->getSelectorsHandler()->xpathLiteral('use_uploaded');
$radioButton = $session->getPage()->find('named', array('radio', $escapedValue));
$radioButton ->click();

Comment: Hi  @Oldskool  i have used below step definition  session = $this->getSession(); // get the mink session  $escapedValue = $session->getSelectorsHandler()->xpathLiteral('use_uploaded');  $radioButton = $session->getPage()->find('named', array('radio', $escapedValue));  $radioButton ->click();

Comment: This might help: http://www.masnun.com/2012/11/28/behat-and-mink-finding-and-clicking-with-xpath-and-jquery-like-css-selector.html

Comment: thank you so much ,,,but now i am getting error "element not visible"